# CURLOPT_URL with {} characters

Tags: libcurl, php-curl

In an example I saw for making a curl connection from PHP, it had this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "{$url}");
```

It seems to actually work, but I don't understand why they showed to wrap the URL in the squiggly braces.  Does that do something magical for CURL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"{$url}"` is completely equivalent to `(string)$url`. Please see: [PHP: Strings - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

- If value type of `$url` is not string, it is converted into string.
- If value type of `$url` is always string, their codes are **verbose** or **nonsense**.
  You should replace `"{$url}"` into `$url`.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
```

You have `{$url}`, but PHP just replaces the `$url`, so the braces are around the url.

Good luck!

**Update:**

From the curl docs and multiple SO questions:

```
-g/--globoff
              This  option  switches  off  the "URL globbing parser". When you set this option, you can
              specify URLs that contain the letters {}[] without having them being interpreted by  curl
              itself.  Note  that  these  letters  are not normal legal URL contents but they should be
              encoded according to the URI standard.
```

Comment: Yes but that doesn't answer the question. What is curl interpreting the {} as doing?

Answer (score 0):

libcurl doesn't interpret the curly braces at all, that's done by PHP itself before the string is passed to libcurl.

You can easily see that for yourself if you try to use such on the command line using curl:

```
$ curl -g '{http://example.com/}'
curl: (1) Protocol "{http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Using -g to switch off globbing since the globbing the command line tool uses will otherwise change the test and it *will* work. Again: the globbing also mentioned in the other answer here is implemented and provided by the *command line tool only* so PHP/CURL has no such support. That's not what you see in use from a PHP program.